# PayU not working in magento

Tags: magento, payu

I installed and configured PayU.pl extension in Magento. But when I test and try to place an order, it shows me the following errors after I try to checkout with PayU.pl as payment method.

```
There has been an error processing your request


Trace:
#0 /home/xxxxo/public_html/lib/payu/sdk_v21/OpenPayU/v2/Order.php(185): OpenPayU_Http::throwHttpStatusException(401, Object(OpenPayU_Result))
#1 /home/xxxxo/public_html/lib/payu/sdk_v21/OpenPayU/v2/Order.php(53): OpenPayU_Order::verifyResponse(Array, 'OrderCreateResp...')
#2 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/community/PayU/Account/Model/Payment.php(272): OpenPayU_Order::create(Array)
#3 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/community/PayU/Account/Block/Redirect.php(40): PayU_Account_Model_Payment->orderCreateRequest(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order), Array)
#4 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): PayU_Account_Block_Redirect->_toHtml()
#5 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/community/PayU/Account/controllers/PaymentController.php(62): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): PayU_Account_PaymentController->newAction()
#7 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#8 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/xxxxo/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/xxxxo/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}

Error log record number: 461458235548
```

Any idea where is the issue and how i can solve it? Its been a while and i am unable to fix this one. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: look for 461458235548 in /var/log/ there you can see the more specific error. then report back to the extension developer. other then that, see @enigmativity